# how to convert a table to an array

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a table like below

```
| item_name | item_value | timestamp |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
|  A | 0.25    | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
|  B | 0.34    | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
|  A | 0.30    | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
|  B | 0.54    | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
|  A | 0.32    | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |
|  B | 0.67    | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |
```

How do I convert it to

```
 [[0.25, 0.34], [0.30,0.54],[0.32,0.67]]
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know how you can get a list `[0.25, 0.34, 0.30, 0.54, 0.32, 0.67]`?

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```py
table = """| item_name | item_value | timestamp |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
|  A | 0.25    | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
|  B | 0.34    | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
|  A | 0.30    | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
|  B | 0.54    | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
|  A | 0.32    | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |
|  B | 0.67    | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |"""
```

What you need to do is:

split the table by newlines

```py
rows = table.splitlines()
```

then iterate over the rows of the table and splitting each by |, taking the item in the 3rd place and then convert it to float

```py
[
    [
        float(row_A.split("|")[2].strip()), 
        float(row_B.split("|")[2].strip())
    ]
    for row_A, row_B in zip(rows[2::2],rows[3::2])
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the values in a simple list, you can chunk them by groups of two using an iterator and the zip function:

```
values = [0.25, 0.34, 0.30, 0.54, 0.32, 0.67]
grouped = [*map(list,zip(*[iter(values)]*2))]

print(grouped)
[[0.25, 0.34], [0.3, 0.54], [0.32, 0.67]]
```

you can also do this using subscripting:

```
grouped = [ values[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(values),2) ]
```

or zip striding subscripts stepping by 2 and offset by 1:

```
grouped = [ list(t) for t in zip(values[::2],values[1::2]) ]
```